# how to modify the regex string

Tags: c++, regex

Said a input string

```
std::string input_string = ";;abc,123;,,;456,def;789,ghi,135,jkl";
```

I want to get only "number,string" pair within semicolon closure from input string. In this case, "456,def" is the only match.

Here is my code

```
std::regex regex("(\\d+),([^,;]+)(?:;|$)");
for (std::sregex_iterator it(input_string.begin(), input_string.end(), regex), itEnd; it != itEnd; ++it) {
    std::cout << it->str(1) << ", " << it->str(2) << std::endl;
}
```

But this code also get "135,jkl" as result

Please help me how to modify the regex string?

Comment: 135,jkl is also "number,string" pair. What other restrictions do you have?

Comment: only "number,string" pair within semicolon closure, but begin and end of string may not have semicolon

Comment: What is `abc,123` not a match, as it is also completely enclosed with semicolons?

Comment: <number,string> combo, not the other way around! @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: This is going to be tough to do without using lookarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add a non-capturing group for the leading semicolon:

```
std::regex regex("(?:^|;)(\\d+),([^,;]+)(?=;|$)");
```

---

Or, since you're iterating through them anyway, do it in AWK way!

```
// iterate through ;-separated fields
for(std::sregex_iterator it(
                input_string.begin(), input_string.end(), std::regex("[^;]+"))
            , itEnd
        ; it != itEnd
        ; ++it)
{
    if(std::regex_match(it->str(0), std::regex("\\d+,[^,]*"))) {
        std::cout << it->str(0) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Why I didn't think of it myself :(

Comment: It's ok, it happens to everyone. :)

Comment: After further test casing, now it cannot pass this simple input "1,a;2,b;3,c". "2,b" will not match :(

Comment: Oh yes, now it consumes the whole first match. I've edited my post, changed the trailing group into an assertion, can you see if it works?

Comment: Thanks again, now it pass all my test cases :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are complicating things!

The following simple regex works just fine:

`;(\d+,[a-zA-Z]+);`

All I am looking for is *more than one digit*, followed by *a comma*, followed by *more than one alphabet*; which is enclosed within *semi-colon on either side*. Make sure the `global` flag is turned on to capture all such cases.

P.S.: I assumed that the string part will contain only English alphabets (a to z, case insensitive).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FpVvcD/3)

Comment: It works fine for the inner groups but misses those at the string's edges.

Comment: That's possible only if the string doesn't begin/end with a `;` and the OP still wants to capture that pair. This wasn't mentioned in the question!